# Generate links using values from the model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following Mvc 4 razor code

```
@foreach (var item in Model.DealDetails) {
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.DetailId)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.AppGuid)</td>
    ....
</tr>
```

I want to generate a link in another `<td>` column for each row. The link will look like

```
<a href="/Control/Action/{item.DetailId}?h={item.AppGuid}">
    Link text
</a>
```

The control and action are in the same project. Is there any help function to do it? I want the link not to be created when item.AppGuid is null.

Comment: How does your routes look like? However you can try `@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Action", "Control", new { id = item.DetailId, h = item.AppGuid}, null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.DealDetails) {
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.DetailId)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.AppGuid)</td>
    @if(item.AppGuid != null){
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("text", "action", "controller", new { id = item.DetailId , h = item.AppGuid}, null)</td>
    }
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks. I want the link not to be created when `item.AppGuid` is null. Is there any way to just add parameters in that function?

Comment: Thanks. I also find a way `@Html.ActionLink("Link", "action", "controller", new { id = item.DetailId, h = item.Guid}, new { style = "display:" + (item.Guid == null?"none":"block")})
`

Comment: yours is the one of solutions. Just use one of them that what you need.